# CentOs 6: Install openssl-devel giving multilib issue

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, pip, centos6

I have CentOs 6.4 64 bit installed on my VPS, when i am trying to install openssl-devel, it is giving me issue given below:

> Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
>          cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
>          pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

```
     1. You have an upgrade for openssl which is missing some
        dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
        solve this by installing an older version of openssl of the
        different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
        yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
        requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
        --exclude openssl.otherarch ... this should give you an error
        message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of openssl installed, but
        yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
        If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
        can remove the one with the missing update and everything
        will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of openssl installed already.
        You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   Protected multilib versions: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.i686 != openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can anyone help me about this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally sorted out.

```
Here is the problem:
I was install python 2.7 First and then openssl-devel. Whenever i access any https repository it gives me error.

Here is the steps to solve the issue:

 1. Install openssl
 2. Install openssl-devel
 3. Reinstall Python 2.7
```